# Opening VSCode using command line with directory path (with space) as an argument doesn't open the directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio Code 0.5.0 on my Windows 8 machine.

I am trying to open VS Code from command line giving directory path as an argument.

`code "D:\Apps\Test App New"` and it doesn't open the directory inside VS Code.
It opens only `D:\Apps` and names it Test.

If I give a directory path which doesn't contain spaces then it opens the path correctly.

`code "D:\Apps\MyNewApp"`

Am I missing any argument options/switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be a bug. You can file an issue here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List

As a workaround you can use

```
cd "D:\Apps\Test App New"
code .
```

**EDIT 2015-09-01:**

VSCode 0.8.0 (insider preview) fixed that issue. You can call now

```
code "D:\Apps\Test App New"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The command I have written has to be  generic and will be triggered from an application. It needs to open all editors with the command `'editor path' 'directory'`. Using 2 commands for all editors or just this editor will not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this link which says that this is a glitch in VS Code that is not resolved yet.

https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/Detail/17159

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is not Link-only answer. I had already explained that "it's a glitch in VS Code that is not yet resolved". The link says the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the folder use this:
first open till apps D/apps

then use: cd "Test App New" this will open it

code "D:\Apps cd "Test App New"
By doing this you can open the folder's which have a space in between.